# What is the representation of the triangle group for the uniform (4 4 4) tiling of hyperbolic disk in terms of Mobius transformations?

Tags: math-history, hyperbolic-geometry, tessellations

I wonder how can one descibe the generators of the triangle group for the tesselation of Poincare unit  disk by triangles with angles $\pi/4, \pi/4 , \pi/4 $ in terms of the action of the modular group on a fundamental triangles.In other words, I mean how can one write the generators of this tesselation in terms of Mobius transformations. I'm completely unfamiliar with the theory of hyperbolic tesselations, and there may be many inaccuracies in my understanding and even with the specific terminology i use.

**Side remark:**

My real purpose is just to verify an historical hypothesis i have on Gauss's tesselation of the unit disk as described in John Stilwell "Mathematics and it's history". Looking at the relevant pages in Gauss's Nachlass (volume 8, p.102-105), I read that the commentor (Robert Fricke) on this fragment of Gauss says that Gauss's drawing (the (4 4 4) tesselation) is intended to be a geometrical illustration for composition of substitutions other then the fundamental generators of the modular group. The substitutions Gauss used are:

$$\frac{128\theta + 37i}{-45i\theta + 13}$$

$$ \frac{121\theta+36i}{-84i\theta+25}$$

Checking the determinants of these substitutions gave $-1$ for the first one and $+1$ for the second one, so this made me suspect that these are Mobius transformations (the only thing that doesn't settle is that $a,b,c,d$ in the Mobius transformation should be real integers, not imaginary integers). But this conclusion is a result of a very shallow reading of Fricke's comments and i lack the proffesional knowledge needed to verify my reading. In addition, there are two drawings in these pages (one on p.103 and the Gauss's tesselation on p.104), and i'm not sure to which drawing Fricke refers.

Comment: Much of the relevant book by Fricke and Klein is presented in Magnus, Non-Euclidean Tesselations and their Groups. The original book in German (1897) was recently translated,  https://bookstore.ams.org/ctm-3/

Comment: @Will Jagy - Thanks very much! i'll try to search thourouly in this book for relevant clues. Anyway, if you know something helpful, i'll be glad i you will write it down.

Comment: see the (4,4,4) entry in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Finite_triangular_hyperbolic_tilings_table

Comment: O.K I looked at the (4 4 4) entry on wikipedia but i didn't find any information that can serve as a clue. Am i missing something?

Comment: No, you are not missing anything.

Comment: @WillJagy - are the generators for the modular group in the unit disk different from those of the upper half plane? I ask that because it seems that conformally transforming the upper half plane into the unit disk is itself a Mobius transformation.

Comment: The unit disk and the upper half planes are two different models of hyperbolic geometry, and their isometry groups are two different groups. So yes, the generators for the modular groups in those two different groups are different from each other.